# Properties of the set $S=\{f_n(x)=f(x^{1+\frac1n}) : n\in N \} $ where $ f(x)$ is a Lipschitz function in the space $C[0,1]$ with sup norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ denote the space of all real-valued continous functiona on $[0,1]$ equipped with
$||^.||_{\infty}$ norm.

Let $f\in C[0,1]$ be such that
$|f(x)-f(y)| \le M|x-y|,\forall x,y \in [0,1]$ and for some $M \gt 0$.

For $n \in N$, let $f_n(x)=f(x^{1+\frac1n})$.

If $S=\left\{f_n :n\in N \right\}$. Then

1. The closure of $S$ is compact.
2. $S$ is closed but not totally bounded.
3. $S$ is closed and bounded .
4. $S$ is compact.

It's not difficult to see $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise.I was thinking if uniform convergence will help somehow though I couldn't prove or disprove it.

I am pretty sure $S$ is not closed. I tried to prove by contradiction.

If possible, let $f(x)=f_m(x)$ for some $ m$. Then this equality arises:

$f(x)=f(x^{1+\frac1m}), \forall x\in [0,1]$

I am confused what to conclude from here. Please help me with useful hints. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First check that $x^{1 + 1/n} \to x$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. This can be checked directly, or you can use monotonicity theorems. Using this and the Lipschitz condition, it's easy to see that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. The set $S$ is thus a convergent sequence in $C[0,1]$ (but it's missing the limit $f$).

Answer (score 1):

Let us show that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly.  We have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq M|x^{1+\frac 1 n} -x|$. Let $\epsilon >0$. For $|x| <\epsilon/2$ we have $|x^{1+\frac 1 n} -x|\leq 2|x| <\epsilon$. I leave it to you show that $|x^{1+\frac 1 n} -x| \to 0$ uniformly on $[\epsilon ,1]$. We have proved that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Now it is easy to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, but $f\notin S$. Therefore, $S$ is not closed, which implies $S$ is not compact. Hence option $2,3$ and $4$ are false.